# Oracle Service Bus 12c: Element /definitions/documentation rewritten in effective WSDL of a proxy service

Tags: wsdl, oracle-service-bus

We store a version of a proxy service inside a WSDL document -- into the element /definitions/documentation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
xmlns:tns="http://mynamespace.cz/1.0" 
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" 
name="MyService" targetNamespace="ttp://mynamespace.cz/1.0">
  <wsdl:documentation>
    <version>2.0</version>
  </wsdl:documentation>
```

I can deploy a service to the Service Bus 12c (12.2.1) and the service works fine. When I display the WSDL from the Service Bus console (so called resource WSDL), the WSDL is as I expect and includes:

```
<wsdl:documentation>
  <version>2.0</version>
</wsdl:documentation>
```

However, if I get the effective WSDL (created by Service Bus from resource WSDL) by the URL:
http://myserver:port/sbresource?PROXY/MyService/MyService

The element documentation is overwritten:

```
<WL5G3N0:documentation>
        2.0
</WL5G3N0:documentation>
```

The element version is completely missing, however it's content is still present.

Can you please advise why this is happening and if there is any workaround available? We need to preserve the element "version", so that the parsers will be able to retrieve the service version.

My aim is to get an easy to use solution for the service consumers, i.e. have a single WSDL as the source of information and let the WSDL simple as possible to be easily parsed by XPath.

Comment: Have you tried adding a namespace to `<version>`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should example xml in an xsd documentation annotation be escaped?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1087293/should-example-xml-in-an-xsd-documentation-annotation-be-escaped)

Comment: Yes, I tried adding a namespace, but the element dissapeared also. When I add an attribute, it is also removed. Only the text contents of elements remain within effective WSDL.

Comment: Of course CDATA is one of the workarounds, but I prefer having a single XML document and to reach the subelements of /definitions/documentation by simple XPath addressing.

Answer (score 1):

I think OSB takes short-cuts when generating effective WSDLs, and whatever is in the documentation element just gets `data()`'d.

As an alternative, would it help if you [accessed the design-time WSDL](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/osb/develop/GUID-74E456BD-7C52-43AC-A666-DD07760CF81A.htm#OSBDV2240) that the effective WSDL is based on?

e.g. `http://host:port/sbresource?WSDL/project_path/wsdl_name`

Comment: Resource WSDL contains the version element, but not other information which is present in effective WSDL (endpoint address etc.). Using two WSDLs is too complicated for the consumers, also bearing in mind resource/effective WSDL is pretty-much Oracle SB specific thing and hard to understand for people who 'just need the WSDL to get the work done'.

Comment: I guess the most robust approach would be to include the version as a `fixed` element in the WSDL, or as a variable that can be returned from some sort of 'status' operation.